# Why is my function from onlick not changing the innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, attributes

I am a beginner in Javascript, and I am trying to create a website that has some questions for people to fill out.

So right now, I have something like:

```
<head>
    <script>
        function wrong(self) {
            self.innerHTML = "Wrong :(";
        }
        function right(self) {
            self.innerHTML = "Right!";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Who is the better team?: <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name = "q1" value="Celtics" onclick="wrong(this)">Celtics<br><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name = "q1" value="Lakers" onclick="right(this)">Lakers<br><br>
</body>
```

But when I actually create my page with the checkboxes, the text on the right doesn't get changed when I click either of the checkboxes. I have also tried changing the type to "button" but that doesn't have its innerHTML changed either.

I have seen some previous answers saying that I might be trying to change something before an element is loaded. However, if I am calling the function using the "onclick" attribute inside the said element, then I believe it must be loaded at the time of calling.

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: "input" element does not really have "inner" contents .... at least, it's not a wrapper for text that is displayed on the page.  You will probably want to use something like a <span></span> to wrap the text, and then you can set the contents of that span.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inputs cannot have children. They're like `<img>`s. The `Celtics` and `Lakers` exist in separate text nodes (that are not children). Assigning to the `innerHTML` of the input does nothing.

Put the texts into standalone elements of their own, and then you'll be able to change their text.

```js
function wrong(self) {
  self.nextElementSibling.textContent = "Wrong :(";
}

function right(self) {
  self.nextElementSibling.textContent = "Right!";
}
```

```html
Who is the better team?: <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="Celtics" onclick="wrong(this)">
<div>Celtics</div>
<input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="Lakers" onclick="right(this)">
<div>Lakers</div>
```

(while it would be technically possible to select and change the text nodes in your original HTML, having *elements* to change instead of text nodes usually makes more sense)

Comment: Thank you! I am curious what the text node way is?

Comment: `self.nextSibling.textContent = 'foo'`